# How to use my own connection object when using GORM

Tags: go, database-connection, connection-pooling, go-gorm

i would like to customize the connection used by GORM - like implement some kind of wrapper which will execute additional processing on query execution. for example, authorize against third-party service.

i see that there is an interface `Conn interface` which i can implement to have my own processing. but i'm unable to make GORM creating connection of type defined by me.

any recommendations will be welcomed and much appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a struct with the connection object as a compostion.

```
type MyConnection struct {
     gorm.DB
}
```

Then you can implement your own wrapper methods, eg.:

```
 func (db *MyConnection) Commit() *gorm.DB {
     // your code
     return db.Commit()
 }
```

Comment: thank you @stukoi
i need an exact connection, no just an ability to catch and ovewrite Commit

Comment: What do you mean by "exact" connection? Wrapping `Commit()` is just and example I provided. Ofc you can do this for any Method (and any structs, for that matter). Please have a look at embedding structs in Go: https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding